# Extract int from String on SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to extract a number that follows an cardinal "#" from a String in sql server. Also I want to ignore all numbers that aren't attached to the "#" simbol. For that purpose I created something like this:

```
DECLARE @val nvarchar(50)

SET @val = '#5777 some text'

PRINT SUBSTRING(@val, PATINDEX('%#[0-9]%', @val) + 1, 
    PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', SUBSTRING(@val, 
        PATINDEX('%#[0-9]%', @val) + 1, LEN(@val))) - 1)


----------
@val = '#5777 some text':
result = 5777
@val = '#5777'
result = error
```

It works fine if the number the number as some text after it but if the number is the last character I obvisualy get an error stating:

"
Invalid length parameter passed to the LEFT or SUBSTRING function
"

Of course I could do something like:

```
DECLARE @val nvarchar(50)

SET @val = '#5777'

PRINT SUBSTRING(@val, PATINDEX('%#[0-9]%', @val) + 1, 
    CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', SUBSTRING(@val, 
        PATINDEX('%#[0-9]%', @val) + 1, LEN(@val))) = 0 THEN
        LEN(@val) ELSE
        PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', SUBSTRING(@val, 
        PATINDEX('%#[0-9]%', @val) + 1, LEN(@val))) - 1
        END)

----------
result = 5777
```

So my question is: Is there any way to achieve this purpose in a simpler and more efficient way?

Thank you

Comment: Yes, store the number in a separate column in the first place. :)

Comment: @AlvinThompson Unfortunately I can't do that. I can't make changes to the software being used :(

Comment: Why don't you just add a space to the end of the string?

Comment: @podiluska Because I didn't thought of that :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit hacky, but it works for both of your scenarios (following text, no following text):

```
DECLARE @val nvarchar(50)

SET @val = '#5777 some text'
PRINT SUBSTRING(@val, PATINDEX('%#[0-9]%', @val) + 1, 
    ISNULL(NULLIF((PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', SUBSTRING(@val, PATINDEX('%#[0-9]%', @val) + 1, LEN(@val))) - 1),-1),100))

SET @val = '#5777'

PRINT SUBSTRING(@val, PATINDEX('%#[0-9]%', @val) + 1, 
    ISNULL(NULLIF((PATINDEX('%[^0-9]%', SUBSTRING(@val, PATINDEX('%#[0-9]%', @val) + 1, LEN(@val))) - 1),-1),100))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @val nvarchar(50)

SET @val = '#5777 some text'

PRINT REPLACE(@val, SUBSTRING(@val, PATINDEX('%[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]%', @val), 1), '')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you'll be parsing strings on a regular basis, add a [string-splitting function](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/07/t-sql-queries/split-strings) to your toolbox.

```
SELECT string
FROM dbo.SplitString(@value,' ')
WHERE
  string LIKE '#'+REPLICATE('[0-9]',LEN(string)-1)
```